# Weird problem with Rails and Adobe Livecycle pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, adobe, livecycle

I'm building a site in which a catalog (of products) is shown and when clicked a Adobe Livecycle generated pdf will be opened. There are a few form fields and when the submit button is pressed, the fields will be submitted to the url http://localhost:3000/pdf-parser.

This file gets all the parameters and can store them in the database. The problem is to identify which user is sending the data via Pdf? This could be accomplished if I could inject some parameter like user_id into the Livecycle pdf file which would get passsed to the http://localhost:3000/pdf-parser so that I can stamp the user.

I googled for this several times but I couldn't get the answer to this as Adobe Livecycle is a new product.

So, can any Rails coder point me in the right direction? Or is this even achievable?
Or is there any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it using the XFA xml file and dotNet custom built renderer library.

Comment: I have tried to send XFA XML data files to fill up my pdf form so user can make necessary changes to the form and submit back (very similar needs as yours). Im using ColdFusion no Ruby. Using tag cfpdfform it is very easy to supply the pdf and xml and fills up your pdf. But it removes all datasets from PDF !!! I was wondering if your form has any datasets and how your dotNet custom built renderer library is dealing with it. Which library are you using anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you set any cookies when sending the `pdf` over to the user (e.g. go ahead and store something inside the controller's `session` object, e.g. `session[:user_id]=1234`), does Acrobat send back the cookies alongside the submitted form data? (e.g. is `session[:user_id]=1234`?)  If so, then you have your answer.

Comment: Well actually, I did accomplished this using the XFA form of PDF rendering the pdf with the modified XFM XML file.